# Saving DateTime value to local storage

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datetime, xamarin

I'm saving `DateTime` value in local storage using `Xam.Plugins.Settings` package:

```
public static DateTime TestDateTime
{
     get => CrossSettings.Current.GetValueOrDefault("TestDate", DateTime.MinValue);
     set => CrossSettings.Current.AddOrUpdateValue("TestDate", value);
}
```

Then I tried to test the work, but I get a different date. I think this is due to the format of DateTime values. This is a WPF project.

```
AppSettings.TestDateTime = DateTime.Now; // {11-Jun-18 08:36:04}
var s = AppSettings.TestDateTime;        // {11-Jun-18 05:36:14}
```

Other types of data are kept well

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess that it's converted to UTC when it saves and that your timezone is UTC+3. I imagine if you use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead, both values are the same. Am I right? If so, what happens if you use `DateTimeOffset`?

Comment: This plugin does not support to save DateTimeOffset

Comment: I don't know about `AppSettings` for Xamarin, but if it's being saved as UTC time, then you can use `AppSettings.TestDateTime.ToLocalTime()` to convert it back to local time.

Comment: Yea, it automatically convert to UTC time

Comment: add 3 hours to the date ?..?

Comment: I was going to comment on the accepted answer, but I don't have enough reputation, so... just be aware that using ToLocalTime on the default DateTime.MinValue may have a side effect if you are going to check the result against DateTime.MinValue, because `DateTime.MinValue.ToLocalTime() != DateTime.MinValue`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
public static DateTime TestDate
{
    get => CrossSettings.Current.GetValueOrDefault("T", DateTime.MinValue).ToLocalTime();
    set => CrossSettings.Current.AddOrUpdateValue("T", value);
}
```

Use `DateTime.ToLocalTime()`. Thanks [@john](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3181933/john)

Comment: `@` notifications don't work inside questions or answers.

Comment: I did not want to notify him, but only to say that he helped me

Comment: As long as you're aware, that's fine.